# Removing the single pixels from Geotiff bianary image

Tags: python, image, opencv

[image]

This is classified image of satellite. Can anybody tell me how to remove these single pixels of filter out them. Remember this is in Geotiff format. I already applied erosion or dilation techniques but no success.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and any error messages that you receive when running it. You may want to also read the guide on [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a similar question on SO but can't find it. There were a quite good answer that I remade for myself. So here is the method called `particle_filter` that will be the solution for your problem:

```py
def particle_filter(image_, power):
    nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image_, connectivity=8)
    sizes = stats[1:, -1]
    nb_components = nb_components - 1

    min_size = power

    img2 = np.zeros(output.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(0, nb_components):
        if sizes[i] >= min_size:
            img_to_compare = threshold_gray_const(output, (i + 1, i + 1))
            img2 = binary_or(img2, img_to_compare)

    img2 = img2.astype(np.uint8)
    return img2


def threshold_gray_const(image_, rang: tuple):
    return cv2.inRange(image_, rang[0], rang[1])


def binary_or(image_1, image_2):
    return cv2.bitwise_or(image_1, image_2)
```

All you need to do is to call this function and give your binary image as first parameter and *filter power* as the second.
A bit explanation: Whole method - is simply iterating over objects on an image, and if the area of one of an object is less than the `power`, then it is simply *removed*.

Comment: it is working , thanks alot... only problem is that when i use " nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image_, connectivity=8)" it give an error of Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV). any solution??

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try *Median Filter* (`cv2.medianBlur`) which should remove single pixels, but might also have other effect. You need to test it with few different settings and decide if it does provide you acceptable result.

Kernel size should be odd for Median Filter, thus median is used on odd number of pixels (9 for size 3, 25 for size 5, 49 for size 7 and so on), therefore *Median Filter* never introduces new value, thus if you use binary image as input, you will get binary image as output.